# Terraform aws_flow_log not adding IAM role ARN

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc

Every single time I run `terraform apply` every single instance of `aws_flow_log` resources needs to be changed

```
# module.us-west-2.aws_flow_log.flow_log[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_flow_log" "flow_log" {
      ...
      + iam_role_arn             = "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/vpc-flow-log-role" # forces replacement
      ...
```

When I visit the vpc in AWS console I see that the **IAM role ARN** is non-existent.
[image]

Has anyone else encountered this issue? The log destination in this case is an s3 bucket not a `cloudwatch_log_group`. So, this is irrelevant: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/6377.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. If the the `log_destination` is set to an s3 bucket then there is no need to specify an `iam_role_arn` you can just remove the argument from the resource like so:

```
resource aws_flow_log flow_log{
    log_destination = var.log_destination
    log_destination_type = var.log_destination_type
    traffic_type = var.traffic_type
    vpc_id = var.aws_vpc_id
    depends_on = [ var.log_destination ]
}
```

instead of

```
resource aws_flow_log flow_log{
    iam_role_arn = aws_iam_role.vpc_flow_log.arn
    log_destination = var.log_destination
    log_destination_type = var.log_destination_type
    traffic_type = var.traffic_type
    vpc_id = var.aws_vpc_id
    depends_on = [ var.log_destination ]
}
```

in this case `var.log_destination_type` is "s3".